# Why is adding `position = "dodge"` to my `geom_bar` leading to values being displayed incorrectly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(human = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                 stage = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"),
                 class = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
)
```

And want bar chart for each stage on the x-axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = stage, y = class, fill = as.factor(human))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15))
```

[image]

Looks good, but I would like the human elements side by side, so I add `position = "dodge"`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = stage, y = class, fill = as.factor(human))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position= "dodge") + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15))
```

While colums are side by side now, for some reason all class = 1:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your "identies" are 0 or 1. One way to deal with this is to `summarize` your data before you plot it. For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    group_by(human, stage) %>% 
    summarise(class = sum(class)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = stage, y = class, fill = as.factor(human))) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position= "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Okay that works fine, but why is R handling O/I data for the y axis differently in this case? It is numeric/integer not logical.

Comment: @Markus I imagine `geom_bar` needs proportions to stack, which it calculates automatically, but to dodge with "identity" it uses the actual values.

Comment: Am I using the wrong geom for this task? I mean, this would have been easier with excel.

Comment: @Markus I think the advantage of R, ggplot2, etc. is not that they are easier, but that they allow better reproducibility and more control and greater flexibility (and they are free). There are definitely some quirks to deal with, but you'll eventually get the hang of it.

Comment: Just noticed, you do not need to set stat anymore after using summarise.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that avoids the `dplyr` preprocessing to use `stat_summary`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = stage, 
               y = class, 
               fill = as.factor(human))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", 
               position = "dodge", 
               fun.y = "sum")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `stat = "identity"`. So then you'll have to count beforehand.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  count(stage, class, human) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = stage, y = n, fill = as.factor(human))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```